# How to include a html file in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a front page of my website as a wordpress plugin.
I want to include a HTML file also in my plugin. I have used below methods to add html content to my plugin.

in wp version 4.8:-

```
function displayHTMLpage() {
    include( '\template\customPage.html' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'displayHTMLpage' );
```

in wp version 4.8.1:-

```
function displayHTMLpage() {
    $pageHTML = file_get_contents( plugins_url( '\template\customPage.html', __FILE__ ) );
    echo $pageHTML;
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'displayHTMLpage');
```

Now above method are not working in 4.8.2. After i upgraded to this latest version, html file is not loading in the website.
I'm really not sure about the correct method to include a HTML file in wordpress plugin. Please let me know the proper way to do this.

Comment: If you want to use the output of html in WordPress, I advise you to use the twig plugin

Comment: Have you checked for errors?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(/wp-content/plugins/plugin-searchForm/template/customPage.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\home\site\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\plugin-searchForm\plugin-searchForm.php on line 45
I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function displayHTMLpage() {
    $asubHTML = file_get_contents(plugins_url('/myfile/test.php',__FILE__ ));
    echo $asubHTML;
}
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adsense_unblock_divs');
```

Comment: This one didn't help brother.

Comment: yeah wtf is this code, lol. where does 'adsense_unblock_divs' even come from? :D did you mean 'displayHTMLpage' ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I removed the folder "template" and kept the html file in plugin main folder.
But i dont understand why wordpress not reading html file when it was inside another folder. :( :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but for anyone who may come across this, I'm pretty sure the error was the path starting with a backslash, which in Linux would have him pathing from the root directory (/) I assume.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
The problem it that the plugin folder need to be added to the url of the file.

```
function my_function($content) {

// all Plugins directory url
// Need to add the directory of your plugin
$pluginUrl = plugin_dir_url('/index.html', __FILE__);
$content .= '
        <p>
            <hr>
            <iframe src="' . $pluginUrl . 'your-plugin-name/index.html" width="100%" height="700px"></iframe>
            <hr>
        </p>
        ';
// Return the content
return $content; 
}
// Hook our function to WordPress the_content filter
add_filter('the_content', 'my_function');
```